# Using javascript to create a value in url and submit that value via form?

Tags: javascript

I have a site that request that they could send out different urls to clients to track what links are being used. I told them to use google analytics but they are requesting to stay away from it.

What they are asking is they want to send a url to there customers such as,
http://www.yoursite.com/?link=Nameoflink

They want to get that cookie and set it.
Then when the contact form is used they want to be able to submit that link name with the form submission to show what links are being used to go directly to there site.

I was told this is possible but i have no knowledge of that custom of javascript or cookie expertise... =/

Comment: What cookie?  Just visiting http://www.yoursite.com/?link=Nameoflink does not imply that there is a cookie involved. Do you mean they want to get the value of the *link* parameter and send it anytime somebody uses the contact form?

Comment: yeah sorry thats what there requesting.  To somehow inbed that link parameter so that if they visit the page.  That value stays there no matter what pages they visit in the mean time and if they go to the contact form it gets submitted without the person knowing.

Comment: This would almost certainly be better handled server than than with client side JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value of the params passed in through the url with location.search. To get the value of the param, use the `location.search` and then find the specific url value, then set that in another hidden text field or something...

```
if (location.search){ 
  var search = location.search.substr(1).split("&"), 
      url = search.split("=")[1];
  document.getElementById('hiddenInput').value = url;
}
```

Note- the code above assumes that your search string only contains the URL value & that the URL is first. If not, it is likely this will fail. You can update the code to account for that by checking to make sure that `search.split("=")[0]==="url"` or expanding it to parse out all of the search params into an object that you can reference by key.

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, google analytics would make this a lot easier, especially if you had a specific page that would serve as a drop-point, telling you how many people click this special link.

Without google analytics, you could get the GET variable values via a PHP or ASP page script and have them set that way, or you can use soley JavaScript to take care of cookie setting and retrieval.

For JavaScript, these links should point you in the right direction:

JavaScript cookies:
(I can only post one link, but check out W3C School's article on JavaScript cookie handling)

Extract GET values via JavaScript:
http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2163

Comment: W3C Schools? Who? There are two organizations that you appear to be conflating. The **W3C** who publish most of the standards that the WWW depends on, and **W3Schools** who publish low quality, security hole ridden tutorials about things relating to the WWW. … and your link appears to be broken.

Comment: Woops, typo on the W3CSchool (was sopposed to be W3School).  The link is broken?  I just clicked it and it worked fine...  Also, while W3School might not provide the most stunning code, it still serves as an excellent JavaScript DOM reference, and a nifty place to get a basic idea (and code examples) of how something JavaScript related works.  Which site would you use for a reference?

Comment: Hmm, the link appears to be working now … although it isn't a very good example, using regex to get the query string instead of `location.search`, and using the deprecated `unescape`. For references, the W3C specs and Mozilla JavaScript reference are usually the best options.